# Perl Net Interface and Perl newt in openSUSE

Tags: linux, perl, rpm, opensuse, zypper

We have some perl script which are working fine in centOS 7. Now I trying to run the same scripts in openSUSE.But I could not find perl Net Interface and perl Newt packages in openSUSE. can anyone please help how to install those packages?

```
Can't locate Net/Interface.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Net::Interface module) (@INC contains: /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.26.1/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.26.1 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.26.1/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.26.1 /usr/lib/perl5/5.26.1/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/5.26.1 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl) at vsappconfig line 15.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at vsappconfig line 15.
```

Line number 15 is related to Perl Net Interface usage.

Tried installing Perl net interface and newt rpm of centOS7.

Expecting Perl net interface and newt package compatible for openSUSE.

Comment: `Net::Interface` is not available under openSUSE repos. Instead install using CPAN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't find the Perl-module as a system package, you can install it through [cpan](http://www.cpan.org/misc/cpan-faq.html#How_install_Perl_modules):

```
$ cpan
```

to open up a Cpan shell and:

```
install Net::Interface
```

and the other packages you need.

Comment: and what about perl Newt

Comment: If you can't 'install Newt' you might be able to download and install it manually https://metacpan.org/release/AMEDINA/Newt-1.08/source/README

Answer (score 2):

```bash
    perl -MCPAN -e 'install Net::Interface'
```

however you might need to install `CPAN` first

Comment: and what about perl Newt?

Comment: perl -MCPAN -e 'install Newt'